# Login con MySQL y visual basic

Tags: mysql, vb.net, .net

Estoy haciendo un login, pero en una parte del código me muestra un error `Fatal error encountered during command execution`, el error aparece al llegar a la linea `oDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()`

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal, ayuda por favor.

Este es mi código:

```
        connection = New MySqlConnection

        'Conexion a MySQL
        connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.cadena_conexion
        connection.Open()

        'Query hacia la BD
        Dim query As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        query.Append("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users ")
        query.Append("WHERE username = @Nombre")
        query.Append("AND password = @Clave")


        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query.ToString, connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Clave", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40)

        cmd.Parameters("@Nombre").Value = nombre
        cmd.Parameters("@Clave").Value = clave


        oDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Y si pones un espacio antes del AND: ` AND password = @Clave ` se resuelve?

Comment: @RogerTorné, ya lo hice, pero ahora recibo otro error "La cadena no se reconoce como DateTime válido. Hay una palabra desconocida al inicio del índice 0."